# Resizing/Scaling images in a view by setting custom CSS width

Tags: image, drupal, imagefield

### Problem

I'm doing some maintenance and changes on a Drupal site, but I'm not an expert. My problem is the following. I have a view that produces an HTML table by fetching some field values and putting them into the table columns. One of these field is an image. Unfortunately each image has a different size (images are uploaded by users), and so the overall table looks ugly. I would like to resize/scale images so that they all have the same width. I know I can use CSS to set the image width to a fixed value, and let the height adjust accordingly:

```
<img src="..." style="width:70px"/>
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to make Drupal output this custom HTML when processing my view. Currently the produced HTML looks like this:

```
<img 
  class="imagefield imagefield-field_imgsmall" 
  width="100" 
  height="39" 
  alt="" 
  src="http://www.mysite.org/sites/default/files/foobar.png?1292948397">
```

and I guess this is produced by one of the view's fields (namely `field_imgsmall`).

First question is: what is that number after the `?` in the `src` URL? And where does it come from? (Each image has a different number in the corresponding `src` URL)

### What I've tried

I've noticed that in the "edit view" mode, when selecting a field, I can check the option *Rewrite the output of this field*, and there I can mix HTML and substitution patterns. However, I've seen that one of the substitution patterns that's available to me (`[field_imgsmall_fid]`) is actually producing the entire HTML above ... so I can't customize it.

What can I do? Am I going in a totally wrong direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the imagecache module, which allows you to resize images (and cache the results, so the resizing process rarely happens).

Here's a walkthrough:

http://2bits.com/articles/drupal-using-imagecache-with-views-and-cck-imagefields.html

Comment: thanks! imagecache did the trick. I also found this [video](http://blip.tv/file/256997) useful for understanding how to configure it.